# Deployment to new Azure Resource Group and Web Site failing

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I created a new ASP.NET MVC Web Application in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3. During the creation, I checked the box that I want to host my application on Azure as a Web App. When configuring the Azure Web App Settings, I created a new Resource Group, a new App Service plan, and a new Resource Group.

When it tried to create the project and deploy it, I got the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "MissingRegistrationForLocation",
    "message": "The subscription is not registered for the resource type 'components' in the location 'Central US'. Please re-register for this provider in order to have access to this location."
  }
}
```

The Resource Group and web app were successfully created in my Azure portal.

When I right-click my project in VS and select Publish, then select the Azure Web Apps target, a window comes up showing my Microsoft account and showing my Azure subscription but it doesn't show any existing web apps.

What do I need to do? I've been searching for a couple of hours now and I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Do you have any updates about this thread?

Comment: I updated all the tools within Visual Studio and the deployment worked without a hitch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a known issue, more info please refer to [MSDN thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/d71994f3-5b2e-4801-9b07-1eec36cffd38/deploying-mvc-app-to-azure-app-services-error-subscription-is-not-registered-for-the-resource-type?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview). Please have a try to update to the latest version of the Azure SDK to fix that. The following is the snipped of the thread.

> This is a known issue for some older versions of the Azure App Service tooling

We can get the Azure SDK easily with [Microsoft Web Platform Installer](https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/) tool.

[image]

Comment: I've seen a few of these threads now, and they are all talking about updating the SDK to resolve this issue, but I'm getting this during an ARM template deployment. I've not found, so far, anything about that.