# Azure WebJob Deploy Error MissingRegistrationForLocation

Tags: azure-webjobs

I am having difficulty deploying a basic Azure WebJob from Visual Studio.  The deployment will successfully create the web app, app service plan and resource group.  However, it fails to deploy the webjob.  I receive the error message below:

Following errors occurred during the deploymnent:
Error during deployment for resource 'resourcename' in resource group 'ResourceGroup':
MissingRegistrationForLocation: The subscription is not registered for the resource type 'components' in the location 'Central US'.  Please re-register for this provider in order to have access to this location.

I've tried multiple subscriptions, resource groups and app service plans in different regions and continue to receive the same error. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Deploy the Azure WebJob in the ‘Central US’, it works for me correctly with Visual Studio 2015 Azure .Net SDK 2.9.5. 
The errors seems like another [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41005563/deployment-to-new-azure-resource-group-and-web-site-failing), it may be caused by old version of Azure SDK. If it is that case, please have a try to use the latest  [Azure SDK](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/archive-net-downloads/). 
And we can follow the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-deploy-webjobs)  to deploy WebJob with Visual Studio.  If we deployed with Azure Resource Manager, some 
troubleshoot common Azure deployment errors with Azure Resource Manager please refer to  [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-common-deployment-errors).

Comment: Updating to the latet version of Azure SDK solved my problem.  Strange that you cannot choose this option directly while installing Visual Studio.

Comment: If it is marked as asnswer that will help more commnities that have the same issue.